# Cypress video freezes on GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: cypress, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow ([here](https://github.com/dariober/Apollo3-testci/actions/workflows/build_and_test.yml), workflow file copied below) running Cypress 12.17.2. The recorded videos invariably freeze 10-11 seconds into the test even if the recording and the test keep going. An example is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19-dHaZSyR_FEi0WasFE40ju04qoF2SrJ/view?usp=sharing).

I tried turning off video compression via cypress config option `videoCompression: false`  but the problem persists.

Does anybody know how to prevent the freezing? There have been similar issues reported (e.g. [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8210)) but no clear solution, if any.

```
name: CI
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - cypress

jobs:
  build:
    name: Test Apollo
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 18.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
          cache: yarn

      - name: Install
        run: yarn --immutable

      - name: Get latest JBrowse
        working-directory: packages/jbrowse-plugin-apollo
        run: yarn run jbrowse create --nightly .jbrowse

      - name: Start MongoDB
        uses: supercharge/mongodb-github-action@1.10.0
        with:
          mongodb-version: 7
          mongodb-replica-set: test-rs

      - name: Setup config
        # Use the same port you have in test:e2e
        run: sed -i 's|http://localhost:[0-9]\+/|http://localhost:8999/|' packages/jbrowse-plugin-apollo/cypress/fixtures/config.json

      - name: Test plugin
        working-directory: packages/jbrowse-plugin-apollo
        env:
          GUEST_USER_ROLE: admin
          MONGODB_URI: mongodb://localhost:27017/apolloTestDb
        run: yarn run test:e2e

      - name: Archive test results
        if: '!cancelled()'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: cypress_results
          path: packages/jbrowse-plugin-apollo/cypress
```

Comment: There is a change in the log at 30 seconds where the `cy.get().selectFile()` is called. Maybe some handler behind the preceding `.check()` action is IO bound? Impossible to tell remotely, but I would challenge the assumption that the video is freezing.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, so I'm just commenting:
Cypress [13.0.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#13-0-0) disables video capture by default and introduces Test Replay.
Video capture caused a lot of issues and didn't work at all on Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Hello @dariober I had the same problem in the past, and what worked for me was making the tests run on the Google Chrome browser on Github Actions instead of Electron, you can do this using cypress/browsers image and cypress-io/github-action@v6 like the following example:

```
name: Test in Docker
on: push
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    # Cypress Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress
    # with browsers pre-installed
    container:
      image: cypress/browsers:latest
      options: --user 1001
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          browser: chrome
```